# Yeoman and Bower not adding Bootstrap CSS (AngularJS generator)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bower, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am following along a [codelab](http://yeoman.io/codelab/scaffold-app.html) on the Yeoman webpage, and so far I've managed to follow along (with a few major hiccups getting my development environment going, but now it doesn't return any errors).

So I made my project folder and ran `yo`, selected AngularJS and run the thing. Fairly soon into the process I got a prompt `? Overwrite package.json?` I answered with `y` and got the following warnings:

```
npm WARN package.json codelab@0.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@>=0.9 included from karma-jasmine will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency jasmine-core@* included from karma-jasmine will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@>=0.9 included from karma-phantomjs-launcher will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency phantomjs@>=1.9 included from karma-phantomjs-launcher will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@~0.12.0 included from grunt-karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6
```

After that, it finished what it was doing, so I ran `bower install` again just to be sure (because of the package.json thing), and then `grunt serve`. Now grunt says done, without errors, but my page only loads `main.css`. I have a strong feeling the `bootstrap.css` file is missing. [This](http://topdeckandwreck.com/stackOverflow/Screenshot%20from%202015-06-19%2022:06:45.png) is what it looks like, when the codelab instructions say it should look like [this](http://yeoman.io/assets/img/codelab/image_12.792e.png).

If you need further information on what was generated, here's a [GitHub repository link](https://github.com/Shooshte/yeoman-codelab).

Any insight on what I'm doing wrong (if anything) is welcome.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

After doing the codelab I had exactly the same problem with the same result as you are getting (warnings and all). I had to just work around the issue by rolling back to Bootstrap 3.3.4.

Just edit bower.json and change the Bootstrap line to:

```
    "bootstrap": "3.3.4",
```

Then run the following and it should work:

```
    bower install
    grunt serve
```

Comment: before editing it out, my bootstrap line had a `^` before the version number (like this `"angular": "^1.3.0"`). Any idea on what that does, and if I should put it back in before the bootstrap version? Other than that, the site looks like it should now, so I'm finally ready to move on with the codelab. thanks

Comment: I believe that just means the requirement is anything higher than 1.3.0. So for bootstrap it was "bootstrap": "^3.2.0", meaning install anything that is higher than 3.2.0. Therefore it goes and installs the latest 3.3.5 which doesn't work. Setting it to 3.3.4 without the ^ says only install this version, nothing higher.

Comment: I had the same problem, worked like a charm form me.

Answer (score 25):

It didn't work for me either. I got a solution from here:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16663

We fixed this issue temporary by overriding our project `bower.json`. For us it works fine, but we are waiting for some solution from Bootstrap.

```
"overrides":{
    "bootstrap" : {
         "main": [
            "less/bootstrap.less",
            "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
          ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

If you stick to a shell, you can just type:

```
bower install --save bootstrap#3.3.4
grunt serve
```

That will ensure that Twitter Bootstrap gets downgraded to a more Bower/yo-angular friendly version and save it as a dev dependency. Grunt will then run 'wiredep' during its 'serve' task and append the bootstrap.css in your project's index.html.

Answer (score 1):

In the `bower.json` file, the dependency version of Bootstrap is set as:

```
"bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
```

By default, that means install the latest version higher than 3.2.0.
As a result, the latest version 3.3.5 is installed and that breaks.

So, remove the `^` sign and replace:

```
"bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
```

with:

```
"bootstrap": "3.3.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal, but I rolled back to Bootstrap version 3.3.4 and setting up like this:

```
bower install --save bootstrap#3.3.4

bower_concat: {
  all: {
    dest: {
      'js': 'path/to/file/_bower.js',
      'css': 'path/to/file/_bower.css'
    }
  }
}
```